# How to write Segment in pagination library code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Mysql Segment ?? not understood properly
in pagination...
Here is my code:

```
  $data['query']=   $this->db->select('auto_id,title,image,thumb')
                   ->get('gallery',$config['per_page']=12,$this->uri->segment(3));
```

where per_page=12

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this->

```
function records($sort_by = 'rpd_id', $sort_order = 'asc', $offset = 0) {
        $limit = 10;
        $data['results'] = $this->rcbs_Model->get_all_data_from_request($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = base_url("rcbs/records/$sort_by/$sort_order");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->rcbs_Model->count_records();
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $data['sort_by'] = $sort_by;
        $data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('booking_data', $data);
 }
```

> here $sort_by = 'rpd_id' (rpd_id)is the default table column by which
>   data will be sorted.
>
> "get_all_data_from_request" is the function by which you will get all
>   data from your table using select query.
>
> base_url("rcbs/records/$sort_by/$sort_order"); rcbs -Controller name
>   'records'->function name itselft
>
> $this->rcbs_Model->count_records() count all the records from the
>   table.